# How to make a canvas proportionally responsive?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, canvas

I am currently working on a pong game with angular for the frontend, the game is drawn inside an html canvas.

here is the html code:

```
<div style="height: 70%; width: 70%;" align="center">
        <canvas id="canvas-container" width="950" height="525" style="width: 100%;"></canvas>
</div>
```

The canvas get proportionally responsive when I reduce the window on the width but it doesn't work the same on the height. See photos below:

Before reducing the window:
[image]
After reducing the width of the window:
[image]
After reducing the height of the window:
[image]

As you can see when I reduce the height it doesn't work the same as the width, is there a way to make the height of my canvas as responsive as the width ?

**EDIT**

When I use vmin instead of % for the css width of the canvas it fixes the problem but another one came. See photos below:

When I totally reduce the window:
[image]
When I totally reduce the window only on the width:
[image]

Comment: use `vmin` maybe can solve that problem. (the problem is that canvas needs to have a defined with always in `px`, or it will be stretched... so I think you need javascript and change width and height attribute based on a formula of aspect ratio when a event listener fired of viewport width changed)

Comment: Using vmin actually fixed it! but now the width isn't responsive anymore because I need to scroll to the right and left when I reduce it, however the canvas get reduced too

Comment: yes, `vmin` means it will get the minimum width and divide it by 100. on the desktop is the height so `vh`, on mobile is `vw` and is automatic. (however canvas need px values or won't work good)

Comment: I have edited my post to show my new issue

Answer (score 1):

After many tests I found out that the best solution for my issue was to use vmin unit for the css of my canvas on the width and the height respecting the aspect ratio(55% of the width is the height)

```
<canvas #gameCanvas id="canvas-container" width="950" height="525" style="width: 100vmin;height: 55vmin;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Happy you got it and happy you share your solution!

Answer (score 0):

var document= document.getElementById("canvas-container");

var width = window.innerWidth || document.clientWidth;

var height = window.innerHeight || document.clientHeight

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You always can use fromEvent rxjs operator

```
  //declare an observable
  height$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
    startWith(null),
    map((_) => {
      const factor = 525 / 925; //relation original: height/width
      const width = window.innerWidth - 50;
      const height = window.innerHeight - 50;
      if (height > width * factor)
        return { height: width * factor, width: width };
      return { height: height, width: height / factor };
    })
  );
```

And use like

```
<div *ngIf="{ dim: height$ | async } as dim">
  <canvas
    #myCanvas
    style="background-color:yellow"
    [height]="dim.dim.height"
    [width]="dim.dim.width"
  ></canvas>
</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6m9nqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: When I try to implement your code I get the error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. on: [height]="dim.dim.height" and [width]="dim.dim.width"

Comment: try use safe operator, [height]="dim?.dim?.height" and [width]="dim?.dim?.width"